# Add serial number to JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I've a JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to add additional key called `order_id` to all objects in this json and set value as objects order in json (serial number). First object in json should have `order_id` = 1, etc.... Amount of objects in json can be different, it's just example.

I expect this json:
Expected result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "order_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "order_id": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Can you share your attempts to resolve the problem, such that others can check it for problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two stages of transformations such as

```json
[ // replicate each objects' index within the array
  //(they always start from 0 and increments by 1)
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&", // replicate all existing attributes
        "$": "[#2].order_id"
      }
    }
  },
  { // increment each of those indexes by 1
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "order_id": "=intSum(1,@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  { // sort by attributes' names
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]